# Content script answer twice on popup message - Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background

I got result but it returns two alerts "Content: This is a test" but in scripts I send only 1 post. 
It works perfect but two answers is too annoying. Help pls.

**Manifest:**

```
 {
"name": "Test",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Test",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["event.js"],
    "persistent": true
 }, 
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval';  object-src 'self'",
"permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
             "js": ["content.js"],
         "run_at": "document_end",
     "all_frames": true
    }
], 
"browser_action": {
            "name": "Do Action",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}}
```

**Popup script.js:**

```
    $("#myButton").click(function(){    


             chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) 
             {      
                      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "content.js" }, function() 
                      {
                              var port = chrome.tabs.connect(tab.id, { name: "port-conn" });
                              port.postMessage({ data: "This is a test" });
                              port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) 
                              {
                                    alert("Content: " + msg.answer);
                              });
                     });
             });
  }...
```

**content.js:**

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) { 
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) { 
    port.postMessage({answer: msg.data});
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

`Content.js` is specified first in manifest so it is now loading when your extension is loaded. Then you are using it via `executeScript` so it runs the second time.
do these changes.

**Popup script.js:**

```
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){                                      
    var port = chrome.tabs.connect(tab.id, { name: "port-conn" });
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) 
         {
             alert("Content: " + msg.answer);
         });
    $("#myButton").click(function(){    
         port.postMessage({ data: "This is a test" });
    });
});
```

That is the point of messaging. if it did not work then you HAVE TO USE `BACKGROUND` SCRIPT AS WELL that just forwards message between `content` and `popup`

Comment: Also of note: `"all_frames": true` will cause as many insertions as there are frames in the document and may result in similar symptoms.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved.

In manifest

```
"content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
         "js": ["content.js"],
     "run_at": "document_end",
 "all_frames": true
}
```

],

it runs content.js on every page and

```
{ file: "content.js" }
```

Run it again in active tab. So thats why one tab run content twice.